# Starting with a false statement, how can one prove anything is true?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, fake-proofs, proof-theory, formal-proofs

So I've been learning a bit of logic for class and heard that if you begin with a false statement, you can then prove anything to be true, however I don't entirely understand what this means or how to do it.

For example, if $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, can you prove that $1=0$?

Comment: The general statement is of the form "if $P$ then $Q$". It means that if $P$ is true then $Q$ is true, so either $P$ is false or $Q$ is true. In your example, $P$ is always false, so it says nothing about $Q$.

Comment: just for fun! assume there exist $a,b$ relative prime integers such that  $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2}$, we can assume $a$ odd (otherwise we can argue in a similar way with $b$) hence $a \text{mod} 2 =1$. Then we have $a^2 =2 b^2$ hence $2|a$ and a is even i.e. $0= a \text{mod} 2 =1$ Q.E:D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just for fun! assume there exist $a,b$ relative prime integers such that  $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2}$, we can assume $a$ odd (otherwise we can argue in a similar way with $b$) hence $a \;\text{mod} \;2 =1$. We have $a^2 =2 b^2$ hence $2|a$ and a is even i.e. $0= a \; \text{mod} \; 2 =1$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as [the principal of explosion](https://www.google.com/search?q=principal+of+explosion&oq=principal+of+explosion&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5566j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The idea is that as soon as you can prove two contradictory statements from a axiom system (in classical logic), you can prove *anything*.

For instance, if you have proved that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but also have proved (or perhaps just as an axiom) that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then you can argue as follows:

> Clearly, it is either the case that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational or that $1=0$, since we know the former to be true. Since we also know that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, for the previous statement to be true, it must be that $1=0$.

The trick here is that, you can say "this or that" by knowing "this", but from "this or that" you can show "that" by knowing "not this".

---

Note that this process requires starting with a *contradiction* not just with a false statement - but there's no real intrinsic notion of "false" other than "contradictory" within a logical system.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are referring to is vacuous truth, and it's for implications.

The statement:
"If $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then $1=0$" is true logically, because the hypothesis (if $\sqrt{2}$ is rational) is false.

Comment: Because "$False \implies S$" evaluates to true in logic. This is true independent of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... I am not a fan of how that was put ... when it comes to *proving* things, it is not so much that from a false statement you can infer anything.  Logic itself does not care whether things are true or false, and so starting with $P$ does not mean that I can infer anything, even if $P$ turns out to be false.

What *is* true, however, is that you can infer anything you want from a contradiction.

For example, suppose we have your standard contradiction: we have both $P$ and $\neg P$

Now, from $P$ we can infer $P \lor Q$

But if we have $P \lor Q$, and we also have $\neg P$, then we can infer $Q$

And so yes, since $Q$ can be anything at all, we can infer anything from a contradiction.

To go back to the 'false' though:  If you *know* that $P$ is true, then if you assume that $P$ is false (i.e. you have $\neg P$), then indeed you can infer anything you want.  But you can't infer anything you want from a false statement alone.

Answer (score 0):

**What this means** is simply that the following is considered an allowed proof step:

> ... and therefore $A$. But we already know that $\neg A$, so therefore we conclude $B$. Q.E.D.

**How to do it** is just a matter of writing something like the above.

The question you don't ask, but should have, is **why people accept this**. Here my answer would be:

The purpose of a proof is to learn something like "in every time, place, and world where such-and-such premises hold, this conclusion will also hold". This is the same as saying "it is impossible for the premises to be true *and yet* the conclusion is false."

When your proof reaches a contradiction what you have shown is that it is impossible for the premises to be true, *period*. Therefore it is *in particular* impossible for the premises to be true and *at the same time* the conclusion is false. The is what it means that the conclusion follows from the premises.