# Rewrite the propositions without implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I want to rewrite the following types of propositions without the simple or double implication:

1. $p \land \lnot q \to r$
2. $p \land \lnot q \to r \land q$
3. $(p \to r) \leftrightarrow (q \to r)$

So we have to write these propositions without any implication, for example the first proposition like $p \land \lnot q \land r$ or is something else meant?

Comment: It means to produce an **equivalent** formula without $\to$. Your formula is **not** equivalent to 1.

Comment: $A \to B$ is logically equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$, and $A \leftrightarrow B$ is logically equivalent to $(A \to B) \land (B \to A)$. So, ...

Comment: $Α \to B$ is true when $A$ is true and it implies that $B$ is true. So why is it equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$ ?

Comment: @Pingu You can find a list of detailed answers regarding that here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false

Comment: @user400188 I have a question about the case when p is false and q is true. Why is in this case $p \to q$ true?

Comment: What you are asking about here is known as the principal of explosion. The justification for it is that $p\rightarrow q$ should only be false, when the premises is true, and the consequence is false. By virtue of this definition, the principal of explosion states that anything can be proved by assuming falsehood. A great example of this can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972412/starting-with-a-false-statement-how-can-one-prove-anything-is-true/2972430#2972430

Comment: If you wish to have a discussion of this property of material implication, I recommend you ask about it in the logic room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic). In this chatroom you can discuss questions as opposed to just asking them, which in my experience is the best way to learn about implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $p\rightarrow q$ is equivilent to $\lnot p\lor q$.
- $p\leftrightarrow q$ is equivilent to $(p\rightarrow q)\land(q\rightarrow p)$

Using these two definitions, it should be easy to write the propositions $(1~-~3)$ without any [implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) or [biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) symbols.

**Answer:**

> \begin{align}1.&~~~\lnot(p \land \lnot q) \lor r\\2.&~~~\lnot(p \land \lnot q) \lor (r \land q)\\3.&~~~\big((\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot q \lor r)\big)\lor \big((p \land\lnot  r) \land (q \land\lnot  r)\big)\end{align}

Answers $(1~-~3)$ could be improved by simplification using the [distribution laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) if you feel inclined.

Comment: I have found the first two expressions with the equivalences you stated above, too. As for the third proposition, I have found that it is equivalent to

$$((p \land \lnot r) \lor ( \lnot q \lor r)) \land ((q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)) $$

Is it also right? Is it equivalent to your result?

Comment: I must apologise. My original answer contained a mistake, I had written the same term twice $((\lnot p\lor r)\land(\lnot q\lor r))\lor((\lnot p\lor r)\land(\lnot q\lor r))$. Your answer was equivalent to my mistaken answer, but like mine it was not correct. I have since edited the answer to something that is correct.

Comment: After having made again calculations, I have found the result

$$((p \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot q \lor r)) \land ((q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \lor r)) $$

Is it right? Is it equaivalent to yours?

Comment: Hey @pingu, that equation is the same as the one you posted before. Did you make an error typing it?